# Reverse geocoding in Android with touch event

Tags: android, android-emulator

I have gone through several articles through this stack overflow and other related articles with reverse geocoding.

I have intended to find the name of the place with the given latitude and longitude from touch event. I got the latitude and longitude from the touch event but I couldn't get the address from that geo coordinate, it passes in the exception rather then being in the try area,

**here is the code :**

```
public boolean onTouchEvent(MotionEvent event, MapView mapView)
{
     //---when user lifts his finger---
        //---when user lifts his finger---
         if (event.getAction() == 1) {
         GeoPoint p = mapView.getProjection().fromPixels(
         (int) event.getX(),
         (int) event.getY());
                  Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(),
         p.getLatitudeE6() / 1E6 + "," +
         p.getLongitudeE6() /1E6 ,
         Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

         Geocoder geoCoder = new Geocoder(getBaseContext(), Locale.getDefault());
         try {
         List<Address> addresses = geoCoder.getFromLocation(p.getLatitudeE6() / 1E6, p.getLongitudeE6() / 1E6, 1);

         String strCompleteAddress= "";
         if (addresses.size() > 0)
         {
         for (int i=0; i<addresses.get(0).getMaxAddressLineIndex();i++)
        strCompleteAddress+= addresses.get(0).getAddressLine(i) + "\n";
         }
         Log.i("MyLocTAG => ", strCompleteAddress);
         Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), strCompleteAddress,            Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
         }
         catch (IOException e) {

         e.printStackTrace();
         Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), "exception", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
         }
         return true;
         }
         else
         return false;
     }
}
```

please get me to the solution to it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

so The emulator 2.2 has bug associated with Reverse Geocoding. So we need to download version like 2.1 and try. It will provide the desired result

Comment: I see...I first know that the emulator 2.2 has bug associated with Reverse Geocoding...Thanks for your experience.

Answer (score 0):

What exception do you get? Does you App have **INTERNET permission**? I'm pretty sure you'll need this for Geocoder to work (as it calls a Google Service via Internet).

Comment: no, the code doesn,t  provide the intended address,it will neither provide any address rather it jumps to catch section and gives exception in pop up menu  rather then giving the address of the coordinate

Comment: Thus my question - _what_ exception do you get? The exception tells you what's wrong (more or less), so it would be helpful if you could add the stacktrace of the exception to your question.

Comment: finally with lot trial in the emulator 2.2 , I was unable to get the result . however when I download the 2.1 and tested the code , it provide the desired result. So what I found is Emulator 2.2 has bug related to reverse geocoding