# reverse geocoding with touch event in google api not working

Tags: android, google-maps, geocoding

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Reverse geocoding in Android with touch event](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12555032/reverse-geocoding-in-android-with-touch-event)

i want to change the latitude and longitude from the map to location address but i coulnot get the result ,it throws exception to catch portion and prints the part of catch portion . This code is obtained from several tutorials where the sereenshot shows the result but i coulnot get it .What might the cause to it,or in api 2.2 ,it is not valid.

**here is the code**;

@Override
     public boolean onTouchEvent(MotionEvent event, MapView mapView)
     {
     //---when user lifts his finger---
     if (event.getAction() == 1) {
     GeoPoint  p = mapView.getProjection().fromPixels(
     (int) event.getX(),
     (int) event.getY());
     Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(),
             p.getLatitudeE6() / 1E6 + "," +
             p.getLongitudeE6() /1E6 ,
             Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

`Geocoder geoCoder = new Geocoder(
         getBaseContext(), Locale.getDefault());
     try {
         List<Address> addresses = geoCoder.getFromLocation(
             p.getLatitudeE6()/1E6  , 
             p.getLongitudeE6()/1E6, 1);

         String add = "";

         if (addresses.size() > 0) 
         {
             for (int i=0; i<addresses.get(0).getMaxAddressLineIndex(); 
                  i++)
                add += addresses.get(0).getAddressLine(i) + "\n";
         }

         Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), add, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
     }
     catch (IOException e) {  
          Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), "uffff.... exception", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
         e.printStackTrace();
     }   
     return true;
 }
 else                
     return false;

 }`

please help me to get through it ,I have been under it for a long time .and thanks for advance

Comment: What happened with your [**question**](http://stackoverflow.com/q/12555032/1050058) ?

Comment: I couldnot get the address from the latitude and longitude provided to the code,I think there is no error in the code eventhough no output .what is the cause of it?

Comment: how you solved the problem related to it? is it the emulator problem?